# How do I change the sequence of API Apps in an Azure Logic App

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure Logic App containing a number of API Apps. I now have to add an API App in the processing between 2 previous API Apps similar to:

[HttpListener] -> [API App A]

needs to be changed to:

[HttpListener] -> [API App B] -> [API App A]

Is there any way of doing this without having to delete all API Apps after the insertion point, put in the new API App and the re-create the sequence of the following API Apps? 
Can I re-order an existing sequence of API Apps in a Logic App?
Or, can I insert an API App at specific stage in the Logic App sequence of API Apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new designer allow you to drag and drop actions, so one way to achieve this is, assuming you have httpListener --> APIAPP A

1) Add the new action APIAPP B at the end. httpListener --> APIAPP A --> APIAPP B
2) Drag and drop the action to the position required httpListener --> APIAPP A --> APIAPP B

I hope this helps, Wagner.

Answer (score 1):

At this point of the preview, no. It's a known limitation. The team is working hard on adding this functionality to the designer in the future.

Having said that, you could edit the JSON definition of the Logic app using Visual Studio or by going to https://resources.azure.com and make the change there. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Panagiotis. Yes, it is certainly possible to modify the JSON manually in Code View or on https://resources.azure.com. I had just hoped for the Designer to be able to handle this, as modifying the JSON by hand imposes a great risk of making a mess of things - particularly in complex scenarios. At least I have a workaround, while I wait for new features in the designer. Thanks.

Comment: In the obvious category, I always copy the entire thing to a notepad before mucking about.